# Fuzi for iOS (XML/HTML Parser), removing parts

Tags: ios, xml, swift, swift2

I am using Fuzi as my XML/HTML parser. When I get a piece of HTML with `let content = doc.css("#content")` and then try to `content.css(".content-image-left").first?.rawXML = nil`, I receive an error saying the setter is inaccessible.

How would I go about setting the rawXML to `nil` or to remove it from the HTML string?

Comment: Fuzi is the descendant of Objective-C's Ono, which serves as a fast Parser rather than an Editor of XML/HTML document(where the most common use case it to scrape a website, parse an RSS feed, or  interface with a XML-RPC webservice). It currently uses techniques like `lazy` properties to ensure itself as being fast, which sacrifices the ability to modify the document.

Comment: If you do want this feature on Fuzi, try opening an issue on its github repository